# Make Python count the number of occurences of dict keys

Tags: python, dictionary, token

I have the following code and no clue why it fails.

```
tokentagocc={}
lemmatokentagdict= {
  "[',']": ("[',']", "['SYM.Pun.Comma']"), "['verursacht']": ("['verursachten']", "['ADJA.Pos.Nom.Pl.Masc']"), "['eine']": ("['Ein']", "['ART.Indef.Nom.Sg.Masc']"), "['Dollar']": ("['Dollar']", "['N.Reg.*2.*3.Masc']"), "['auf']": ("['auf']", "['APPR.Auf']"), "['Ausland']": ("['Ausland']", "['N.Reg.Acc.Sg.Neut']"), "['Soziale']": ("['Soziales']", "['N.Reg.Acc.Sg.Neut']"), "['Verkehr']": ("['Verkehr']", "['N.Reg.Acc.Sg.Masc']"), "['unterschlagen']": ("['unterschlagenen']", "['ADJA.Pos.Gen.Pl.Neut']"), "['rund']": ("['rund']", "['ADJD.Pos']"), "['staatlich']": ("['staatlichen']", "['ADJA.Pos.Gen.Pl.Neut']"), "['die']": ("['der']", "['ART.Def.Dat.Sg.Fem']"), "['alle']": ("['aller']", "['PRO.Indef.Attr.-3.Gen.Pl.Neut']"), "['für']": ("['für']", "['APPR.Acc']"), "['sie']": ("['sich']", "['PRO.Refl.Subst.3.Acc.Pl.*6']"), "['Milliarde']": ("['Milliarden']", "['N.Reg.Acc.Pl.Fem']"), "['in']": ("['ins']", "['APPRART.Acc.Sg.Neut']"), "['dadurch']": ("['dadurch']", "['PROADV.Dem']"), "['20']": ("['20']", "['CARD']"), "['weitergeleiten|weiterleiten']": ("['weitergeleitet']", "['VPP.Full.Psp']"), "['und']": ("['und']", "['CONJ.Coord.-2']"), '[]': ("['']", '[]'), "['Gesundheit']": ("['Gesundheit']", "['N.Reg.Acc.Sg.Fem']"), "['.']": ("['.']", "['SYM.Pun.Sent']"), "['Jahr']": ("['Jahr']", "['N.Reg.Dat.Sg.Neut']"), "['Geld']": ("['Gelder']", "['N.Reg.Gen.Pl.Neut']"), "['Rund']": ("['Rund']", "['ADJD.Pos']"), "['Schaden']": ("['Schäden']", "['N.Reg.Nom.Pl.Masc']"), "['Prozent']": ("['Prozent']", "['N.Reg.*2.*3.Neut']"), "['belaufen']": ("['beliefen']", "['VFIN.Full.3.Pl.Past.Ind']"), "['<unknown>']": ("['Verwaltungsmafia']", "['N.Reg.Dat.Sg.Fem']"), "['Teil']": ("['Teil']", "['N.Reg.Nom.Sg.Masc']"), "['von']": ("['von']", "['APPR.Dat']"), "['40']": ("['40']", "['CARD']"), "['werden']": ("['werde']", "['VFIN.Aux.3.Sg.Pres.Subj']")
}

for tokentag in lemmatokentagdict:
  print (lemmatokentagdict[tokentag]) 
  if lemmatokentagdict[tokentag] in tokentagocc.keys():
    tokentagocc[lemmatokentagdict[tokentag]]+=1 
    print ("doubled") 
  else:tokentagocc[lemmatokentagdict[tokentag]]=1
```

As there is no key in either the first or the second dict that is there is more than one of, I don't know why it is counted 1 for all tuples of (token, tag). At least the word "Ein" should occur more than once.

Tested it with a smaller version of the script but no luck, so I wanted to post the full code. I'm greatful for any advice on this!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have no idea where your claim "At least the word "Ein" should occur more than once" comes from.  The values of `lemmatokentagdict` are all `tuples`s, **not** strings; not **one** of those tuples' items is the string "Ein", though there is just one occurrence of it as a **substring** of `"['Ein']"` -- but you never, ever, check for substrings.  What the flip would you expect as your resulting `tokentagocc`?  (Ideally in a **much smaller** example -- the 1844 characters-string you're using to populate your first dict makes things really hard to follow/untangle)...

Comment: Keys in dict are unique. Maybe you want to calculated count of values?